# Is there an accepted pattern for forms that can be used for "adding new" and "editing existing"?

Tags: angular

I have what is surely a common issue, and that is that I want to have a reactive form that can be used to "add a new entry" or "edit an existing entry."

Right now the form is its own component, and on submit, it uses an event emitter with the new object.

The add and edit actions are separate components that use the form, and communication between them is handled with a service that has an Observable.

The above things "work" in that I can add and edit items, however there are certain issues I encounter that make me think I am missing something.

For instance, if you are adding many things, once you add the first item, how would I re-initialize the form for the next add new?  Since I am using event emitter, I never know when or if the action succeeds.

I also find it harder to handle form disabling while waiting for the action to complete.

I am thinking that having three components for this is not the right way, or maybe it is, which means how I handle the service is not correct?

Answer (score 0):

I supouse that the "clasic" way is using an interface and a function to create the form,e.g.

```
interface IData
{
   name:string;
   surname:string;
}

createForm(data:any)
{
   data = data || {} as IData;
   return new FormGroup({
       name:new FormControl(data.name,Validators.required),
       surname:new FormControl(data.surname,Validators.required),
   })
}
```

So,

```
  this.form=this.createForm(null); //our form is an empy form
  data={name:"Name",surname:"Surname"}
  this.form=this.createForm(data); //our form is form with data
```

Comment: Yes, I have used that in the past.  I think I might be trying to be too fancy with Observables and using async pipe so I don't have to manage the subscription directly.  I was thinking a service with a Subject that is injected into the form might work, but I figure someone surely has a better idea for "advanced" implementations.